# Laravel validation value range between

Tags: laravel

I want my input value of range 9-12 and i am applying

`'check' => 'required|digits_between:9,12'`

`digits_between` calculate the **length of digit**.

but i don't want to validate character **length**. i want to validate only character **value**

```
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'check' => 'required|digits_between:9,12',
        ],
        [
            'check.digits_between'=> 'Value must be between 9 to 12', 
        ]);
```

Comment: I am not sure, but may be this is happen because your `check` field is not an **integer** so. Where `digit` is called a numeric value. So if you change `'check' => 'required|integer|digits_between:9,12',` then it may work

Comment: what do you mean by character value .. as in you only want the number to be `9`, `10`, `11`, or `12`?

Comment: the difference between length vs value....     for example '7'.. its length of character is 1 and value is 7

Comment: so you only want the values of 9 - 12?

Comment: @lagbox  between 9-12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `between`[min,max] rule:

```
'integer|between:9,12'
// or
'numeric|between:9,12'
```

Adding `integer` or `numeric` to make sure that `between` that uses the same system as `size` treats this as a number.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Validation - Available Rules - `between`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-between)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Validation - Available Rules - `integer`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-integer)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Validation - Available Rules - `numeric`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-numeric)